# Jenkins-How to schedule a jenkins job when another job completes on remote machine

Tags: triggers, jenkins, jobs

I have two remote machines: A and B. Both have Jenkins installed.

A: This will build from trunk.

B: To trigger automation.

How can I configure Jenkins job on Machine B, when the build is successful on Machine A?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement because one of the servers that I was using belonged to a different company and therefore, while it would be possible, it was clearly going to take a long time to get buy-in for me to alter their jenkins set-up, even though I was allowed access to monitor it and its outputs. However, if you don't have these restrictions, then you should definitely follow the whole master-slave configuration to address this. That said, here is a solution I came up with and just to note that I've explained why this was a genuine requirement, although I hope to go down the master-slave route myself when possible.

Install the ScriptTrigger plug-in for Jenkins and you can then watch the remote jenkins instance with a script similar to the following:

```
LAST_SUCCESSFUL_UPSTREAM_BUILD=`curl http://my.remote.jenkins.instance.com:8080/job/remoteJobName/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber`
LAST_KNOWN_UPSTREAM_BUILD=`cat $WORKSPACE/../lastKnownUpstreamBuild || echo 0`
echo $LAST_SUCCESSFUL_UPSTREAM_BUILD> $WORKSPACE/../lastKnownUpstreamBuild
exit $(( $LAST_SUCCESSFUL_UPSTREAM_BUILD > $LAST_KNOWN_UPSTREAM_BUILD ))
```

Get the ScriptTrigger to schedule a build whenever the exit code is '1'. Set-up a suitable polling interval and there you have it.

This will obviously only schedule a build if the upstream job succeeds. Use "lastBuild" or "lastFailedBuild" instead of "lastSuccessfulBuild" in the URL above as your requirements dictate.

NOTE: Implemented using a BASH shell. May work in other UNIX shells, won't work in Windows.